# can you help me solving the error below

Tags: php

```
public const $servername;
public const $username;
public const $password;
public const $dbname;

public function __construct() {
    $this->servername = "localhost";
    $this->username = "root";
    $this->password = "";
    $this->dbname = "vodkafairywe";
    $conn = new mysqli ($this->servername, $this->username, $this->password, $this->dbname);        
}
```

I got the following error;

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$servername' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\sometest\db_conn.php on line 5

Line 5 for me is `public const $servername`;

I don't know whats wrong with it

Comment: I think `const` is short form for `constant` which means *that doesn't change*. Maybe you should remove it (all the const in your code)  
(Edit for more...)
read this https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/object-oriented-php-for-beginners--net-12762
and maybe those fields (db access) should be private

Comment: _SIlly question I know_ But do you have a `<?php` on the first line of this script

Comment: I have already tried to remove all the const in code but nothing happens, still getting same error.

Yea I do have <?php at the very first line of this script

Comment: Can I suggest next time you show it, only so I dont have to asking silly questions

Comment: As we are in silly questions, is the code you are showing the whole content of your file ?

Comment: yea im showing it all

Comment: Except the first line `<?php`

Comment: So this is not a class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constants dont have a `$`, and should BE IN CAPS.

`public const SERVERNAME;`

The error gives it away. Unexpected *variable*, not constant! :-P

If you are setting the value (and you are), then you shouldn't be using a constant, therefore, remove it to look like this:

`public $servername;`

Answer (score 0):

Change `public const $servername;` to `public $servername;`
Constants can not be used like variables and they are used for fixed values.